# Is there a way to detect if a given header of the C++ Standard Library is included?

Tags: c++, c++11, cross-platform

More specifically, is it possible to detect, at compilation time, if a C++ standard header file is included (let say `<complex>`), and do that in a way that is cross-plateform and cross-compiler ? I'd like it to work with C++11 at least, but for the question's sake, is it possible for any C++ standard ?

I know the implementation of the C++ Standard Library is dependent on the compiler and operating system, but is there a standardized guard name for the header, a macro that I can check the existence of ?

I've run into this : [Detect usage of STL in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980263/detect-usage-of-stl-in-c) , which is a hack not to use the headers, and this : [Is there a way to detect portably that a standard header is included using macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28845655/is-there-a-way-to-detect-portably-that-a-standard-header-is-included-using-macro), which answers with a C++17 feature, and is in fact more about detecting a function.

What I want is to be able to write some preprocessor instruction at a given point in the code that will tell whether the header is included (yet). I checked the source code of (an implementation of) `<complex>` as an example, and `_GLIBCXX_COMPLEX` is defined, but probably only for this implementation.

Comment: I'm really curious why you want to do that

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm not sure of your actual goal, but it would seem that you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816779/check-if-type-is-defined).

Comment: If you want to ensure `<complex>` is included, then `#include <complex>`. I can't think of a good reason to want to detect that it's *not* included, considering the way transitive includes work.

Comment: what do you want to do when the header is included / is not included ?

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: @divinas @Ben I'm using FFTW, and the documentation says that if ```<complex>``` is included, the standard complex type will be used, else ```fftw_complex```. They're more or less the same, but not exactly, and I want to write a specific template if ```complex``` is included after ```fftw3```. I could make a workaround, but I was wondering if the straightforward solution exists, to learn something.

Comment: @DrewDormann It might help, but that't not what I'm asking. I just want to know if there's some universal macro in the sandard headers that I can use.

Comment: @NathanOliver And what would be the long answer :-) ?

Comment: @BrianBi I know that, and it's not. I'm not trying to solve another problem, or maybe I am,  but I really want an answer to that specific question, since I wasn't able to find any documentation on it.

Comment: you can check if a type is defined. Thats not the same as checking if a particular header is included or not. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625105/how-to-write-is-complete-template

Comment: if you want to know if `complex` is used or not and ask how to check if a header is included then that is a xy problem. xy problem roughly means: You cannot check if a header is included, it is not a viable solution to your actual problem, but there are other ways to check if `complex` is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** : No, there is not, apart from the C++17 feature `#if __has_include(<complex>)`. Not with defined macro anyway.

**Long answer** : there are two parts to the answer. What I read from some headers, and the tests I ran on differents OS with differents compilers.

**Warning** : I will write also about C, as some compilers uses the same macros. I also use the shortcut 'for C' and 'for C++' instead of 'when the header `complex.h` is included' and 'when the header `<complex>` is included'.

Ok, here's my best answer as for now.

#### About C and `complex.h` :

In C, the existence of the macro
`_Complex_I` is the only macro that I think should be defined in any `complex.h` header, as it is specified by the ISO C99 (cf. ISO/IEC 9899:1999/TC3 text). The tests I ran shows that this is a realistic hypothesis. There are some additionnal macro used, such as `_COMPLEX_H` that seems to be defined when compiling with GCC,
and `_C_COMPLEX_T` when compiling with MSVC. There might be others, I didn't find them, please don't hesitate to add them.

But it is C, not C++, and one should not mix both.

#### About C++ and `<complex>` :

The C++ standard (ISO/CEI 14882:2011) does not specify such macro. In fact, it does not specify the inclusion of any macro (at first glance).
It does specify the existence of the `complex` class however, but this does not answer the question.
For what I read, `_COMPLEX_` and  `_C_COMPLEX_T` seems to be defined in the `<complex>` header for
LLVM-clang and MSVC, but also in the `complex.h` for the apple implementation of the C math library (libm). 
However, my tests with the LLVM-clang compiler on macOS failed showing those macro, and I can't find the file where I read that information.
I also found that g++ is defining `_GLIBCXX_COMPLEX`.

If one wanted to do that with a C++ older than C++17, a solution would be to test with the given compilers and architectures the code will run onto.
That is quite bad, but it's the closest answer I get.

### The tests :

I give here the code that I run on the different OS, the compiler options, their version, and the results they prompt. `_Complex_I` was indeed defined for all C headers.
I wasn't able to run the test on macOS with GCC and G++, but I bet that `_Complex_I` will be defined with  GCC and `_GLIBCXX_COMPLEX` with G++.

#### Tests for C++

G++ -std=c++11 v9.3.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 :
`_GLIBCXX_COMPLEX`

G++ -std=c++11 v11.2.0 on windows 10 (via Cygwin) :
`_GLIBCXX_COMPLEX`

MSVC default c++11 option v14.29.xxxxx.x on windows 10 :
`_C_COMPLEX_T`
`_COMPLEX_`

Apple LLVM-clang -std=c++11 v10.0.1 : None (doesn't mean there is none, just that I don't know which one)

#### Code for C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main(){

#ifdef _COMPLEX_
    std::cout << "_COMPLEX_" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifdef _C_COMPLEX_T
    std::cout << "_C_COMPLEX_T" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifdef _COMPLEX_H
    std::cout << "_COMPLEX_H" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifdef _Complex_I
    std::cout << "_Complex_I" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifdef _GLIBCXX_COMPLEX
    std::cout << "_GLIBCXX_COMPLEX" << std::endl;
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

#### Tests for C :

GCC -std=c99 v9.3.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 :
`_Complex_I` `_COMPLEX_H`

GCC -std=c99 v11.2.0 on windows 10 (via Cygwin) :
`_Complex_I` `_COMPLEX_H`

MSVC -std=c99 v14.29.xxxxx.x on windows 10 :
`_Complex_I` `_C_COMPLEX_T`

Apple LLVM-clang -std=c99 v10.0.1 : `_Complex_I`

#### Code for C:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main(){

#ifdef _COMPLEX_
    printf("_COMPLEX_\n");
#endif

#ifdef _C_COMPLEX_T
    printf("_C_COMPLEX_T\n");
#endif

#ifdef _COMPLEX_H
    printf("_COMPLEX_H\n");
#endif

#ifdef _Complex_I
    printf("_Complex_I\n");
#endif

#ifdef _GLIBCXX_COMPLEX
    printf("_GLIBCXX_COMPLEX\n");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

#### To sum up :

MSVC is defining `_C_COMPLEX_T` whatever C or C++ used, and also `_COMPLEX_` for C++. `_Complex_I` is always defined for C, and G++ seems to define `_GLIBCXX_COMPLEX` whatever the plateform (test to be done on macOS) for C++.